# UPnP Port Mapping/Forwarding to different IP (iOS/Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, upnp

**Disclaimer: I've carefully read every similar topic here and did a google search. None of those answered my questions, so I would like some further explanation.**

Is there a framework for **iOS/Objective-C** which can change the **local IP address** of an UPnP port mapping?

I've already tried: TCMPortMapper, miniupnpc, libnatpmp ...

If I haven't missed anything all libraries only supply a function like

- *addPortMapping(internalPort,desiredExternealPort,Protocol, description)*

Is there a possibility to change the **destination IP** of the UPnP mapping in the frameworks I used or do I need a specific library?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "change the destination IP of the UPnP mapping"? You cannot change it. Did the specification of found gateway and local address it was found from is insufficient when you create port mapping?